# How to move an object , with a shape seen in the background scene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, shapes, swift4.2

The moving object (say a box or a circle) should follow the shape around with user finger until the time runs out. For example ,there is a moving path seen to the user on the screen then he will have to cross the path by moving finger along with the path .

Comment: You can't just ask someone to make a game for you on Stack Overflow - if you have a specific issue, then ask that instead.

Comment: @George_E Okay.